# What is this widget called in GTK?

Tags: c, gtk

I was wondering that currently we have gtk.TextViewWidget to display the contents of widget. I was wondering is there any way to make a type of My Computer Properties dialog box where there are different panels at top and one can click on any one of them to display the contents of that property.

Can anyone give me some good advice on how to proceed making this?

Comment: You want a GtkNotebook for tabbed interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need a [`GtkNotebook`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkNotebook.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand fully what you mean, but it sounds as if you could easily just stack a [GtkTreeView](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkTreeView.html) on top of a [GtkTextView](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkTextView.html) to achieve what you want. Populate the tree view with a suitable [model](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkTreeStore.html) holding the items in your computer (how to find this information is of course a separate problem), and then as a tree item is clicked, modify the text view's [buffer](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html) to display the associated information.

Comment: I meant a type of tabular structure  where when I click on one tab I see one information when on the other the other. just like the Computer Properties in Windows xp .